# Timepicker error

Tags: javascript

Hola que tal tengo un timepicker de la siguiente manera

```html
<div class = "col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" > 
   <input id="hora" size = "16" type = "text" value = "" />    
       <span class = "add-on" > 
            <i class = "icon-th" > </ i> 
       </ span>  
   </ div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/site.js"></script>

 $(function () {
            $('#hora').timepicker();
        });
```

al momento de ejecutar este me mandada el siguiente error
timepciker is not function 
alguien puede apoyarme 
saludos.

---

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Revisa si `jquery.timepicker.js` está cargado en la página.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtengas tu primer medalla, ahora sobre tu pregunta: src="jquery.timepicker.js" es la ruta correcta del archivo?

Comment: Solo te falta cargar jquery antes que las otras tres librerías de js

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que lo único que te falta es cargar jquery antes que el resto, porque el siguiente ejemplo a mí me funciona.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" > 
   <input id="hora" size = "16" type = "text" value = "" />    
       <span class = "add-on" > 
            <i class = "icon-th" > </i> 
       </span>  
   </div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


<script>
 $(function () {
            $('#hora').timepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de las librerías que tratas de importar.

Como en tu código veo un `.timepicker` eso me hace pensar que tu plugin no es el normal de [bootstrap-datepicker](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-datepicker) que vi que estabas tratando de importar, así que asumiendo que se trate de [jquery-ui-timepicker-addon](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon) tu código quredaría así:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hora').timepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fontawesome.com/v3.2.1/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>



<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <input id="hora" size="16" type="text" value="" />
  <span class="add-on"> 
            <i class="icon-th"></i>
       </span>
</div>
```